# Too many open files when using nginx + tornado to handle 5000 websocket connections

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, tornado

I'm testing my tornado gateway server which handles 5000 connections well without nginx. Then I add nginx and run 2 servers to handle 5000 connections. Unfortunately `[Errno 24] Too many open files` occur.

I've already modified kern.maxfiles and kern.maxfilesperproc in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, that's why my server handled 5000 connections well without nginx.

```
kern.maxfiles=104000
kern.maxfilesperproc=100000
```

After [Errno 24] occured, I've already modified `worker_rlimit_nofile` to more than 10000 and restarted nginx, but the error still occured, and I'm confusing now...

Here is my configuration of nginx in `nginx.conf`.

```
worker_processes 5;
worker_rlimit_nofile 10240;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 2048;
    use kqueue;
}

http {
    #charset utf-8;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    # Enumerate all the Tornado servers here
    upstream websocket {
        server 127.0.0.1:60000;
        server 127.0.0.1:60001;
    }

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    keepalive_timeout 65;
    proxy_read_timeout 200;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml
               application/x-javascript application/xml
               application/atom+xml text/javascript;

    # Only retry if there was a communication error, not a timeout
    # on the Tornado server (to avoid propagating "queries of death"
    # to all frontends)
    proxy_next_upstream error;

    server {
        listen 60017;

        location ^~ /static/ {
            root /path/to/app;
            if ($query_string) {
                expires max;
            }
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://websocket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
    }
}
```

I expect the connections would be dispatched to my tornado servers and run well. But the error occur at about 1000 connections...

I have no idea how to fix it, it would be appreciated to have some help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't see the phrase maxfiles in that configuration file...

Answer (score 1):

Check you open file limit via ulimit (`ulimit -n` work only in current session):

```
root# ulimit -a | grep "open files"
open files                      (-n) 1024
root# ulimit -n 5000
root# ulimit -a | grep "open files"
open files                      (-n) 5000
```

Example for set open file limit as 5000 only for root user, but after this fix need reboot (do not forget replace root user to the you web user):

```
echo -e "root\t\t-\tnofile\t\t 5000" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Comment: `-n: file descriptors  65536`   this is what I get with `ulimit -a` ...   I don't think this is the way to solve it...